# When do we need std::shared_future instead of std::future for inter-thread synchronization?

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future, shared

I tried to test how `std::shared_future` is shared between different threads as these threads all calls its `wait()` function, and wake up after its `signal` is called. As below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    promise<void> p, p1, p2;
    auto sf = p.get_future().share(); // This line
    auto f1 = [&]() {
        p1.set_value();
        sf.wait();
        return 1;
    };
    auto f2 = [&]() {
        p2.set_value();
        sf.wait();
        return 2;
    };
    auto ret1 = async(launch::async, f1);
    auto ret2 = async(launch::async, f2);
    p1.get_future().wait();
    p2.get_future().wait();
    p.set_value();
    cout << ret1.get() << ", " << ret2.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints `1, 2` and works fine.

Then I changed the line of `auto sf = p.get_future().share();` into `auto sf = p.get_future()` using oridinay `future` object, not the `shared` version, compile and run. I got the same result: while I expected that for the non-shared version, only 1 thread will successfully `wait` and return while other threads will hang. But seems still the program runs OK.

So my question is: when do we need to use `std::shared_future` instead of `std::future`? Or it's just an object like `std::shared_ptr`, as a simple wrapper of `std::future` so that it could be passed around?

I mean is there any case that non-shared future doesn't fulfill the need or scenario. Would you help to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "shared" part of `shared_future` is not about the *waiting* but *getting*.

> I expected that for the non-shared version, only 1 thread will successfully wait and return while other threads will hang.

No, this is completely safe, you can wait on a future from as many threads as you want (it is a const member, hence thread-safe) and all must unblock when the result is set. But be warned that `wait()` cannot be called after someone called `get()`.

The difference is in how you get the results. Remember, `std::future` stands for a future result set by `std::promise`.

- `std::future::get()` returns by value. It can only be called once and thus only from one thread.
- `std::shared_future::get()` returns a const reference. It can be called many times from multiple threads. Of course be careful about the thread-safety of the underlying object - whether its methods are really thread-safe.

Furthermore `std::shared_future` can be cloned and multiple such objects can refer to a single shared state, i.e. linked to a single promised object. The shared state exists as long as some future/promise points to it, like `std::shared_ptr<State>`.

In your case, you are slightly misusing `std::shared_future sf`, each thread that awaits the result should get its own clone. That way, its lifetime is safe. The envisioned workflow is:

- `std::promise` is created, the [first] `future` is obtained from it.
- The promise is given to the producer, consumers do not know about it.
- The future is given to [each] consumer [which can clone it and pass it along if necessary].

> I mean is there any case that non-shared future doesn't fulfill the need or scenario. Would you help to explain?

Having two consumer threads, both awaiting the result. `std::future` would require for exactly one thread to call `get` and somehow share that result with the other. Although both could have called `wait()`. On the other hand `std::shared_future` allows both to "view" the result since it is const. Yes, one has to copy the result if it needs to be passed around but that is unavoidable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One copy of std::shared_future cannot be used from different threads except for copying. It is necessary that each thread has its own copy of std::shared_future.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future

> Access to the same shared state from multiple threads is safe if each thread does it through its own copy of a shared_future object.